# Why is this sentence a syntactic consequence of another one?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, lambda-calculus

From Alexander Williams's ["Arguments in Syntax and Semantics"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/arguments-in-syntax-and-semantics/A7AC7E14BEC601EAA03D0DF8354C65EC) (pp. 213-214):

> "Formula (10b) has (9b) and (7b) as provable syntactic consequences,
> by Conjunction Elimination in the scope of an existential quantifier."
>
> [image]

How is (7b) a syntactic consequence of (10b)? Ignoring the $\lambda e_1$  and "$Do(e_1,Floyd)$"for a moment, I believe that we can prove (in first order logic) that $$\exists e_2[Cause(e_1,e_2)\land \exists e_3[Become(e_2,e_3)\land Hard (e_3,glass)]]$$ syntactically entails
$$\exists e_3[Hard (e_3,glass)]$$

The author doesn't give any inference rules for lambda calculus, so I don't know how to deal with the lambda. I could guess that the way it works is that we just add $\lambda e_1$ at the beginning of both lines above, and that would be a valid inference, but if so, I still don't see how $\lambda e_1[\exists e_3[Hard(e_3,glass)]]$ syntactically entails $\lambda e_1 [Hard(e_1,glass)].$ Also, I don't see how to eliminate $Do(e_1,Floyd)$.

Comment: These translations seem extremely weird to me. What is the source? (When you quote from a source, you should *aways* give the citation. In addition to the genera principle of citing your sources, it will also give people more context for understanding your question).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I added the source to the question. It's a text by a philosopher of language, and they often write strange things...

Comment: The formalism the translations are based on is event semantics, explained e.g. in chapter 11 [here](https://eecoppock.info/bootcamp/semantics-boot-camp.pdf).

Comment: Maybe have a look at the rule of existential closure, which makes it possible to go from an event lambda abstraction to an existential sentence, see above reference p. 434.

Comment: (10) says that Floyd do an Event that Caused the glass to Become Hard and (9) says that to become Hard means to Harden. Instantiating (10) to a specific event $a$, we have that Floyd do $a$ and $a$ Caused $e_2$ such that $\exists e_3 [B(e_2,e_3) \land H(e_3, \text {glass})]$. Up to now, we have used the propositional rule of [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) to unpack the formula.

Comment: Now we instantiate the existential quantifier with a new event $b$ to get $B(e2,b) ∧ H(b,\text {glass})$ and using Conjunction elimination again we get $H(b,\text {glass})$. Now we re-introduce the lambda operator to get $\lambda e_1 [H(e_1, \text {glass})]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So is there an inference rule that allows to pass from $\lambda e. P(e)$ to $P(e_0)$ for some $e_0$ (basically the same rule as passing from $\exists x Q(x)$ to $Q(x_0)$ where $x_0$ is a new variable that we declared)? Or are you using something different?